# How to iterate web service response object in Katalon Studio script?

Tags: katalon-studio

I am getting the response object via web service call using Katalon Studio and now I want to check whether the given user values are present in response object or not. How can I do that? Please help.
Code::

```
ResponseObject getUsersResponse = WS.callTestCase(findTestCase("getResponse"),
    ["serviceName":"insertUserRequest"])
```

Answer (score 1):

They have a dedicated documentation page regard to your current concern. Here is the [link](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Handle+Response+Messages), it might worth to look at it and use appropriate keywords.